# How to append commits of unrelated branches?

Tags: git, rebase, cherry-pick

I want to append two unrelated branches together. Let's say I have something like this:

```
a---b---c---d (A)


      A---B---C---D---E---F (branch)
     /
e---f---g---h (B)
```

I want the result to be:

```
                       A'---B'---C'---D'---E'---F' (branch)
                      /
a---b---c---d---e'---f'---g'---h'
```

I tried with `git rebase --onto d e` (HEAD is B) but I get conflicts, and my intention is only to append the commits with THEIR content, not to check two commits and see the differences and solve the conflicts. In other words I want the parent of `e` witch initially is not set to be `d`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: do A and B share a common ancestor?

Comment: no, what I mean by unrelated is that they have nothing in common

Comment: Check out the option of `--allow-unrelated-histories` when doing git merge

Comment: I don't want to use git merge because I want a linear history

Comment: to make one point clearer about `e'`: you want to discard the content of `d` and have the exact same content as `e`, correct ?

Comment: yes, exactly like this and also to keep all the history of b such as merges and the open branches if possible

Answer (score 2):

The key is to make `d` become the parent of `e`. So, create `e'`, the tree of which is the same with the tree of `e` and the parent of which is `d`. Replace the letters like `d`, `e` in the commands with their real commit sha1 values.

```
# Save the commit message of e in a temp file
git log -1 e --pretty=%B > tmp_msg.txt

# Create e'
newbase=$(git commit-tree -p d -F tmp_msg.txt e^{tree})
echo $newbase
rm -fv tmp_msg.txt

# Use rebase or cherry-pick to apply other commits onto e'
git checkout $newbase
git cherry-pick f g h
git checkout f'
git cherry-pick f..F
# Or
git rebase --onto e' e h
git rebase --onto f' f F

# Move the branches to the new heads
git update-ref refs/heads/<branch> F'
# Or
git switch <branch>
git reset F' --hard
```

If the graph of the other commits is more complicated than the example in the question, consider `git rebase -i -r --keep-empty` to do elaborate operations. You could also use `git commit-tree` to recreate them one by one like `e'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly cut-and-paste to form the architecture that you describe. You will have to proceed in two stages because the A-F branch will not magically come with you.

Your diagram is very unfortunate because you have used some names twice. I will try to disambiguate by using better names. Start with this:

```
a---b---c---d (A-the-branch)

      A---B---C---D---E---F (branch-the-branch)
     /
e---f---g---h (B-the-branch)
```

So first:

```
git rebase --onto d e~1 B-the-branch
```

That will give you:

```
a---b---c---d---e'---f'---g'---h' (B-the-branch)
```

But A-F has been left behind. So now:

```
get rebase --onto f' A~1 branch-the-branch
```

But you *cannot* prevent merge considerations from happening; a rebase *is* a merge. (More precisely: a rebase is a series of cherry-picks, and a cherry-pick is a merge.) Just to remind you why that is: you cannot in any way edit a commit, including moving it (giving it a different parent). The only way to apparently rearrange the architecture is to make *all new commits* that are effectively like *copies* of your original commits. But the only way that Git will make new commits out of whole cloth is by *merge logic*.
You can add

```
-Xtheirs
```

to resolve any conflicts automatically in favor of the copied commits, but you cannot not merge.